# Can't pull posts from a subreddit that were posted before 12/03/2020 using PRAW

Tags: python, pycharm, timestamp, reddit, praw

I am using the reddit API to get about a years worth of submissions(posts) and all of their first string comments and not the replies.  I've set up the code to pull everything from 01/01/2020 to now and from the posts it does pull I get all the first strings comment (over 8000 comments!). The issue is that I can't seem to get it to pull anything older than 12/03/2020. I've tried using `time_filter = 'year'`, changing the `limit` argument to `None`, and checked to see if it was because there are too many posts by setting it to get everything older than 12/15/2020 with a limit of 150, which wasn't the issue.  I've also gone on the subreddit to make sure that older posts exist and they do and used unix timestamps instead of the datetime timestamps.
I'm using Python and PyCharm.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue or something else to try?

Here is the portion of my code responsible for getting the posts:

'''

```
posts = []
janOne = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
janOneTimestamp = janOne.timestamp()

for post in reddit.subreddit("SuicideWatch").search("subreddit:SuicideWatch", limit=None):
    if post.created_utc >= janOneTimestamp:
        #print(post.created_utc)
        posts.append([post.title, post.score, post.id, post.subreddit, post.url, post.num_comments, post.selftext, datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(post.created_utc)])

posts = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns=['title', 'score', 'id', 'subreddit', 'url', 'num_comments', 'body', 'created'])
print(posts)
posts.to_excel(r'C:\Users\eag5834\Documents\CommStudyProject\RedditPosts_DigBata.xlsx', index=False)
```

'''

Comment: Have you checked how many posts it's returning? I believe there's a limit for the search API call, maybe 100 or 1,000. You might need to call it with `after` specified, see https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_search

Comment: @kimbo Yep I tried doing posts before 12/31/2020 and only got 49. I also tried getting posts with post.created_utc greater than 5/1/2020 `and` post.created_utc less than 6/1/2020.  When I try that, it doesn't give me any

I know it says max for limit is 100, but I've previously gotten over 200 but only from dates after 12/2/2020
@kimbo